# Matlab: Creating 3D array from a vector

Tags: matlab

I don't think I know tricks to use repmat in Matlab yet. I tried a number of combination and I am not able to achieve what I need.

I have a vector A of size 1 x 20. I just want to stack A to create 3 x 5 x 20 size matrix. Can you please help ?

Comment: Please have a look through [this tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/academia/student_center/tutorials/launchpad.html) and [this documentation for `repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A = 1:20;
reshape(repmat(A, [15, 1]), [3,5,20])
```